# jQuery-Chains in an AngularJS $timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jstree

Am I mistaken or is AngularJS' `$timeout` function buggy when it comes to jQuery-Chains (in this case jsTree)?

An exception is raised

```
$.(...).jstree(...).on is not a function
```

This is my snippet:

```
$timout(function() {
    $("#foo").jstree().on('select_node:jstree', onSelect)
});
```

When not chaining the `.on()` but having it in an extra line like

```
$("#foo").on('select_node:jstree', onSelect)
```

there is no exception beeing thrown and the onSelect works fine.

Any hint is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you must download jstree and include that your project
https://github.com/vakata/jstree/zipball/3.2.1

Overview

Include a jsTree theme
Setup a container
Include jsTree
Create an instance
Listen for events
Interact with your instances

Answer (score 0):

`$(selector).jstree()` returns an instance of `$.jstree.core`, and not a jQuery wrapped object.

Thus, you cannot chain it with the `.on()` handler setter - problem is completely unrelated from Angular / timeout issues of course.

Comment: I have another angularjs question.  Are you willing to comment on it?  The user who posted an answer took off without elaborating.  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588344/how-do-i-connect-this-interval-service-to-a-view

Comment: The strange thing is, that the chain does work, when not wrapped in a $timeout