# How do I connect this interval service to a view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The AngularJS documentation for `$interval` gives an example of using `$interval` in a controller to manage a timer that the user can play with in a view.  You can read the code for the official example at [the angularJS documentation page by clicking n this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

I have tried to move the code from the example controller back into a service so that the code can be more modular.  But the app is not connecting the service to the view.  I have recreated the problem in [a plnkr that you can play with by clicking on this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/7kzVrDGH0A0eQAQdsyum?p=preview).

**What specific changes need to be made to the code in the plnkr above so that the `mytimer` service can be available to the view as a property of the controller that imports the service?**

To summarize here, 'index.html` is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example109-production</title>
    <script src="myTimer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="exampleController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="intervalExample">

<div>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <label>Date format: <input ng-model="mytimer.format"></label> <hr/>
    Current time is: <span my-current-time="mytimer.format"></span>
    <hr/>
    Blood 1 : <font color='red'>{{mytimer.blood_1}}</font>
    Blood 2 : <font color='red'>{{mytimer.blood_2}}</font>
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="mytimer.fight()">Fight</button>
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="mytimer.stopFight()">StopFight</button>
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="mytimer.resetFight()">resetFight</button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code for `app.js` is:

```
angular.module('intervalExample',['ExampleController'])
```

The code for `exampleController.js` is:

```
angular
.module('intervalExample', ['mytimer'])
.controller('ExampleController', function($scope, mytimer) {

    $scope.mytimer = mytimer;

});
```

The code for `myTimer.js` is:

```
angular
.module('mytimer', [])
.service('mytimer', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope, $interval) {

    var $this = this;
    this.testvariable = "some value. ";

        this.format = 'M/d/yy h:mm:ss a';
        this.blood_1 = 100;
        this.blood_2 = 120;

        var stop;
        this.fight = function() {
          // Don't start a new fight if we are already fighting
          if ( angular.isDefined(stop) ) return;

          stop = $interval(function() {
            if (this.blood_1 > 0 && this.blood_2 > 0) {
              this.blood_1 = this.blood_1 - 3;
              this.blood_2 = this.blood_2 - 4;
            } else {
              this.stopFight();
            }
          }, 100);
        };

        this.stopFight = function() {
          if (angular.isDefined(stop)) {
            $interval.cancel(stop);
            stop = undefined;
          }
        };

        this.resetFight = function() {
          this.blood_1 = 100;
          this.blood_2 = 120;
        };

        this.$on('$destroy', function() {
          // Make sure that the interval is destroyed too
          this.stopFight();
        });

}])

    // Register the 'myCurrentTime' directive factory method.
    // We inject $interval and dateFilter service since the factory method is DI.
    .directive('myCurrentTime', ['$interval', 'dateFilter',
      function($interval, dateFilter) {
        // return the directive link function. (compile function not needed)
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var format,  // date format
              stopTime; // so that we can cancel the time updates

          // used to update the UI
          function updateTime() {
            element.text(dateFilter(new Date(), format));
          }

          // watch the expression, and update the UI on change.
          scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
            format = value;
            updateTime();
          });

          stopTime = $interval(updateTime, 1000);

          // listen on DOM destroy (removal) event, and cancel the next UI update
          // to prevent updating time after the DOM element was removed.
          element.on('$destroy', function() {
            $interval.cancel(stopTime);
          });
        }
      }]);;
```

All of [the above code is assembled in "working" form in this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7kzVrDGH0A0eQAQdsyum?p=preview) that you can use to diagnose and identify the solution to the problem.  **So what specific changes need to be made to the code above to allow the user to interact with the service through the view?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you didn't inject the $interval to the `mytimer` service and did try to use it.

secondly, you had scope issues in the `mytimer` service:

```
stop = $interval(function() {
    if (this.blood_1 > 0 && this.blood_2 > 0) {
        this.blood_1 = $this.blood_1 - 3;
        this.blood_2 = $this.blood_2 - 4;
    } else {
        this.stopFight();
    }
}, 100);
```

when declaring a function you are creating a new scope, meaning the `this` is pointing to a new scope. you can either use `bind` or to use the `$this` variable you declared in line 5. (in ES2015 you could simply use the arrow function).

also you declared the module exampleController twice in `app.js` and in `mytimer.js`.

Take a look at this working Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/34rlsjzH5KWaobiungYI?p=preview

Comment: @CodeMed - As asked, just comment out the line `angular.module('intervalExample',['ExampleController']);` on **app.js** and it will work just fine

Comment: @AlonEitan Thank you!  Are you willing, though, to help me truly understand the underlying issue?  My question is how to set it up so that multiple controllers can be part of the same app, with the ng-app from index.html pointing to app.js, which in turn manages all the various controllers in the app, including but not limited to ExampleController.  I am trying to learn how this all works.

Comment: @AlonEitan The plnkr is just a reduced version of my actual app.  The reason I am being picky is that my actual app has other controllers, so the solution of deleting the file or commenting the only line in this app.js does not apply to real world of having multiple controllers in the same app.

Comment: @CodeMed both Dan and myself are from Israel and it's 1:26am here so i'll take a look on this tomorrow

Comment: @AlonEitan Your engagement enabled me to find the answer.  I will try to add it as an edit to his answer, but will post it here in case the edit does not take.  I am adding the edit to his answer as an attempt to give him the credit while also making it easier for other users to read later.  The answer was to change `exampleController.js` to the following:  `angular
.module('ExampleController', ['mytimer'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', 'mytimer', function($scope, mytimer) {

 $scope.mytimer = mytimer;
 
}]);`